# How to deal with characters like ":" or "?" that make invalid filenames?

Tags: filesystems, filenames, thunar, fat32

I just tried to move a directory containing music files with `thunar 4.10`
It complained that a file name was invalid.

It turned out that one file name (song title) contained a question mark.
I suspected that this was a problem, removed the question mark and could indeed copy the file.
Adding the "?" back in was not possible. I also tried it with `rename` on the command line but that didn't work either. (not sure what thunar uses under the hood, so this test might be moot)

Now if a question mark makes the file name invalid, how could this file be created in the first place? I created the files with `SoundJuicer` from a newly obtained CD. I was able to play the file (with "?" in the name) in various players.

What's going on here? Can I have the "?" in the name or not? Why is the file manager unable to handle such files while other applications seem to be ok with it?

**Update:**
Next song has a ":" in it. Same problem as with the "?".

> These are not invalid characters to Unix; typically only the NUL character and the / character are invalid filenames (the / being the directory separator).

This was what my intuition told me as well, because I never had any issues with file names in Linux and could throw pretty much everything sensible at it and it worked ok. This is what motivated the question here. I never encountered invalid file names before.

> Were you trying to move the files to a USB stick? If so, is that stick formatted as FAT32 or as a native Linux filesystem?

The target is indeed a USB stick that I bought today. I opened `gparted` and it is formatted as FAT32.

I'm not exactly sure but that's a Windows thing right? And Windows has a bunch of characters that it doesn't support, apaprently including `?` and `:`. Am I right?

Comment: These are not invalid characters to Unix; typically only the NUL character and the `/` character are invalid filenames (the `/` being the directory separator).  Now in the _command line_ you may need to _quote_ the `?` (and ` ` and `*` and similar) - e.g. `touch 'test?'` -  to ensure the shell doesn't try to interpret them, but that's a different problem.

Comment: Were you trying to move the files to a USB stick? If so, is that stick formatted as FAT32 or as a native Linux filesystem?

Comment: @roaima sorry, for the missing information, I edited my answer to include it.

Comment: Just tried it on my machine and Thunar 1.6.10 ( xfce 4.12 ) and did not have a problem creating and moving files with `?` or `:` in the name. I also assume, as  roaima already pointed out, that rather the filesystem does not support the special characters.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These characters `?` and `:` are not valid on a FAT32 filesystem, so if that is where you need to copy your files you *will* need to rename them.

From the command line you can use command-line tools such as `rename` (sometimes known as `prename`) to replace these characters with `_` or even to remove them:

```
rename 's/[?<>\\:*|\"]/_/g'    # Change invalid characters to _
rename 's/[?<>\\:*|\"]//g'     # Remove invalid characters
```

I am not familiar with `thunar` so I do not know if there is a way to perform this substitution/replacement operation directly.

I have just found [Linux copy to fat32 filesystem: invalid argument](https://superuser.com/questions/178025/linux-copy-to-fat32-filesystem-invalid-argument/178040#178040) which suggests adding this into the `pax` command (another tool to copy files), so that you can keep your full filenames on your local disk but convert the filenames *during the copy* to your USB device:

```
pax -rw -s '/[?<>\\:*|\"]/_/gp' *.mp3 /media/usb_device
```

If the complete filenames are really important to you, I would suggest that you reformat the USB stick to use a Linux-native filesystem such as `ext4`. (There are [Windows drivers available](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2fsd/) for the `extN` family of filesystems if that's necessary.)

Comment: The newly bought USB stick came with some encryption software on it that I totally ignored. Had I paid some attention to it, I would have noticed that the executables are .app for Mac and .exe for Win, which could have been a hint on checking the file system.

Answer (score 4):

It is definitely allowed to have `?` in a filename.

From the POSIX standard:

> Filename
>
> A sequence of bytes consisting of 1 to `{NAME_MAX}` bytes used to name a file. The bytes composing the name shall not contain the `<NUL>` or `<slash>` characters. In the context of a pathname, each filename shall be followed by a `<slash>` or a `<NUL>` character; elsewhere, a filename followed by a `<NUL>` character forms a string (but not necessarily a character string). The filenames dot and dot-dot have special meaning. A filename is sometimes referred to as a "pathname component". See also Pathname.

So the only characters a filename may *not* contain is `\0` (signifying an end-of-string) and `/` (which is a path separator).  Also, the filenames `.` and `..` are special and may not be used by files that you create.

Some characters are special *to the shell* and needs to be escaped or properly quoted for the shell to not treat them as globbing patterns.  The question mark is one of those characters, as it usually stands for "any one character" in shell globbing patterns.

My guess is that Thunar is choosing not to handle these filenames as the characters `:` and `?` (and `<`, `>`, `"`, `|`, `\`, and `*`) are not allowed *on Windows*, and it wants to force you to use filenames that are portable between Windows and Unix. I don't know the reasoning behind this, but it could have something to do with making Thunar work on filesystems shared with Windows machines.

**EDIT**: After the question was updated with further information, it is clear that the files will need to conform to Windows naming rules as the filesystem is indeed a Windows filesystem.

[@roaima's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/299674/116858) shows how to rename files using the Linux `rename` utility. This is a another solution that will work on systems without `rename`, a `bash` function, `fatmv` that renames files containing illegal Windows characters by changing them to underscores (`_`):

```
function fatmv {
    name="$( basename "$1" )"
    destdir="$2"

    fat_name="$( tr ':?<>"|\\*' '_' <<<"$name" )"

    if [[ -n "$destdir" ]]; then
      fat_name="$destdir"/"$fat_name"
    fi

    echo mv -f -- "$1" "$fat_name"
}
```

If a second argument is used, this is treated as a destination directory the which the renamed file should be moved:

```
$ fatmv '<illegal>:filename?' /mount/fat_disk/
mv -f -- <illegal>:filename? /mount/fat_disk//_illegal__filename_
```

Test this as is, and then remove the `echo` to make it actually do something.

Comment: So how can the OP handle these files in their GUI filemanager?

Answer (score 2):

The `?` is a special character that has significance in bash, You can work with it by escaping it with `\`

ie:

```
touch test\?
```

will make the file:

```
test?
```

and you can move it with

```
mv test\? /new/loction/test\?
```

Edit: The same for any special character, such as `.`

You also need it for file names that contain spaces

```
this is a file
```

would have to be moved with:

```
mv this\ is\ a\ file <location>
```

Comment: But how do you escape a `?` in a name when you're using a GUI filemanager?

Comment: Thank you for the info. I'm sure the makers of the thunar file manager were aware of that? Taking care of the "problematic" files individually seems tedious. Can I configure thunar somehow to be aware of the problem and do the escaping? Or is the command line my only option?

Comment: My Apologies...Honestly It's been so long since I've done a GUI file operation that even reading that you were using Thunar, it didn't click that this was a GUI issue. I'll look for more information for you.

Answer (score 1):

To apply [@roaimas answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/299674/115933) to all files under a given directory, you can use the command

```
find /path/to/dir -exec rename 's/[?<>\\:*|\"/_/g' {} \;
```

which applies `rename` to all files.

Answer (score 0):

To apply @serv-inc and @roaimas to not only replace `?` and `:` but also all other characters (e. g. unicode characters which are not FAT32 valid), that are not in `[A-Za-z0-9]` with `_` of the names of all files in a directory, you can use the following:

```
for file in *.mp3 ; do var=$( echo $file | sed -e 's/[^A-Za-z0-9]/_/g'); var=${var:0:60} ; var=${var%_mp3}.mp3 ; mv "$file" $var ; done
```

I also had problems with too long filenames of MP3 files on FAT32, so it cuts the basename off at 60 characters (I don't know the max. length, but 60 characters works for me).
**Be careful** this **overwrites** the original file names by moving the files.